# View refreshing not triggered when ObservableObject is inherited in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

`ContentView2` view is not refreshed when `model.value` changes, if `Model` conforms to `ObservableObject` directly instead of inheriting `SuperModel` then it works fine

```
class SuperModel: ObservableObject {

}

class Model: SuperModel {
    @Published var value = ""
}

struct ContentView2: View {

    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.value)
            Button("change value") {
                self.model.value = "\(Int.random(in: 1...10))"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Worth reporting to Apple, please submit feedback.

Comment: @Asperi the solution exists if at least one published property is part of supermodel. see my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is working variant of your example. See that to be able to work, not only chaining the publishers is required, but at least one Published property. So or so, it could help in some scenario.

```
import SwiftUI

class SuperModel: ObservableObject {
    // this is workaround but not real trouble.
    // without any value in supermodel there is no real usage of SuperModel at all
    @Published var superFlag = false
}

class Model: SuperModel {
    @Published var value = ""
    override init() {
        super.init()
        _ = self.objectWillChange.append(super.objectWillChange)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.value)
            Button("change value") {
                self.model.value = "\(Int.random(in: 1...10))"
            }
        }

    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

changing the code to

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.value)
            Button("change value") {
                self.model.value = "\(Int.random(in: 1...10))"
            }
            Text(model.superFlag.description)
            Button("change super flag") {
                self.model.superFlag.toggle()
            }
        }

    }
```

you can see how to use even your supermodel at the same time

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use ObjectWillChange to solve the problem specified.

Here is the working code:

```
import SwiftUI

class SuperModel: ObservableObject {

}

class Model: SuperModel {
    var value: String = "" {
        willSet { self.objectWillChange.send() }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Model Value1: \(model.value)")
            Button("change value") {
                self.model.value = "\(Int.random(in: 1...10))"
            }
            Text("Model Value2: \(model.value)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what's the point of using inheritance? I could use SuperModel directly as my model. In reality SuperModel has a bunch of Publishers and Model is supposed to add some more

Comment: You can inherit class objects. However, ObservableObject is a protocol. As per (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject) documentation, ObservableObject synthesizes published properties. You cannot inherit this behavior.

Comment: So, how could I make Model conform to ObservableObject protocol? `class Model: SuperModel, ObservableObject {}` is forbidden "Redundant conformance of 'Model' to protocol 'ObservableObject'"

Comment: I have edited my answer above that solves your inheritance and ObservableObject conformance issue.

Comment: Your variant does not work for me, which Xcode do you use to test?

Answer (score -1):

This really looks like heavy defect.

> ```
> class SuperModel: ObservableObject {
> }
>
> class Model: SuperModel {
>     @Published var value = ""
> }
> ```

as I see the `value` is changed and keep new one as expected, but `DynamicProperty` feature does not work

The following variant works for me (Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

```
class SuperModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var stub = "" // << required !!!
}

class Model: SuperModel {
    @Published var value = "" {
        willSet { self.objectWillChange.send() } // < works only if above
    }
}
```

Also such case is possible for consideration:

```
class SuperModel {
}

class Model: SuperModel, ObservableObject {
    @Published var value = ""
}
```

Comment: the trouble is that you need to do the same for every published property in you Model. see how to solve it in my answer.